# Bottle: Enabling errors output to the browser instead of viewing error_log

Tags: python, bottle

i'm trying to figure out how to enable error output to the browser instead of logginf via ssh all the time and 'tail -f error_log' ?

In dev instance we just did `debug =True`, now in the production server?
Here is my config:

```
DocumentRoot /home/nikos/public_html

<Directory /home/nikos/public_html>
    Require all granted
</Directory>


Alias /static /home/nikos/public_html/static

<Directory /home/nikos/public_html/static>
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>


WSGIPassAuthorization On

WSGIDaemonProcess clientele user=nikos group=nikos home=/home/nikos/public_html
WSGIScriptAlias /clientele /home/nikos/public_html/clientele.py process-group=clientele application-group=%{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess downloads user=nikos group=nikos home=/home/nikos/public_html
WSGIScriptAlias /downloads /home/nikos/public_html/downloads.py process-group=downloads application-group=%{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess www user=nikos group=nikos home=/home/nikos/public_html
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/(?!phpmyadmin) /home/nikos/public_html/www.py process-group=www application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

Comment: I don't understand something - why can't you continue to use `debug=True`? (But please note that it is considered *insecure* and not recommended to send errors to the browser in production.)

Comment: Because when we move from dev to production we deactivate this line: `#app.run( host='superhost.gr', port=8080, debug=True ). So now that i'm on production how do i enable it?

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying, now I understand. I'll leave an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [debug flag](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.debug) might do what you want:

```
import bottle

# during your init
bottle.debug(True)
```

But I want to reiterate: *you shouldn't do this*. It's a [security hole](https://labs.detectify.com/2015/10/02/how-patreon-got-hacked-publicly-exposed-werkzeug-debugger/).

Comment: Great thank you very much, i mistakenly used `app.debug=True' instead.